# Cassandra issue changing a MAP column in milisseconds

Tags: java, dictionary, cassandra

I have an API running in java using the driver  com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.8 and consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM. My cassandra structure has 9 nodes, divided in 3 datacenters.

I have a columnfamily with a column defined as STATUS MAP and, to simplify, 2 endpoints. The first one, lets call it NEW, calls an insert in this columnfamily setting STATUS as {new Date(),"NEW"}. The second one, lets call it PURCHASE, to be called afterwards updates the STATUS field with STATUS[?] = 'PURCHASED' with ? being new Date() as well.

The update in the purchase method is enclosed in a lightweight transaction to avoid concurrency and fetches .wasApplied() from a batch instruction using consistency level LOCAL_SERIAL.

I have noted that sometimes, when PURCHASE is called milisseconds after NEW, that wasApplied returns true but it has not added the PURCHASE status. Any ideas?

Comment: Every time you called new Date() it's give you the current timestamp.So for the second one, it will insert a new row instead of updating the first one row

Comment: I see what you mean but that's not whats happening since it would replace the NEW for PURCHASE. What happens is that the map remains only with the first status